# TypeScript Generics Omit & Pick don't work as expected

Tags: typescript, generics

In the normal run of affairs Omit + Pick of a typescript property yields the same type that you started with.  So this works:

```
export interface IEntity {
  id: number;
  retrievedAt: number;
}

type retrievedAt = Pick<IEntity,'retrievedAt'>;
type entityWithoutRetrievedAt = Omit<IEntity,'retrievedAt'>;

const myEntity:IEntity = {
  id: 1,
  retrievedAt: 123456,
}

const myEntity2: retrievedAt & entityWithoutRetrievedAt = {
  id: 2,
  retrievedAt: 8765432
}

// Allowed - no errors
// retrievedAt & entityWithoutRetrievedAt is equivalent to IEntity
const myEntity3: IEntity = myEntity2;
```

However, as soon as a generic is involved, the same logic break down quickly. Why?

So I can't do this:

```
export abstract class TimestampService<E extends IEntity> {
  static markRetrievedAtTime<E>(entityWithoutTimestamp: Omit<E, 'retrievedAt'>): E {
    const retrievedAt: Pick<E, 'retrievedAt'> = {
      retrievedAt: 123465
    }; // Error: The type string does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof E'
    //   Type '{ retrievedAt: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<E, "retrievedAt">'.
    // Types of property 'retrievedAt' are incompatible.
    //   Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'E["retrievedAt"]'.(2322)

    const entity: E = {
      ...entityWithoutTimestamp,
      ...retrievedAt
    };
    return entity;
  }
}
```

Is there a way of achieving Omit + Pick (same property + type) with a generic type signature?

Comment: `markRetrievedAtTime<E>` should be `markRetrievedAtTime<E extends IEntity>` - that's why you get an error about `retrievedAt` - because `E` is unconstrained. And it's a different `E` to the one in the class.

Comment: The error in your code doesn't relate to `Pick` or `Omit`; it's that static members of a class have no access to the instance generic type parameters. So `markRetrievedAtTime` doesn't see the `E` from `TimestampService<E>`.  To "fix" that it seems you make `markRetrievedAtTime` generic in its own type parameter with the same name `E` (but that is misleading; you could have called it `X` or anything else), and this `E` is unconstrained (it does not `extends IEntity`) so the compiler doesn't know what to do with `E["retrievedAt"]`.

Comment: There are actually quite a few errors in the code and you've only asked about one of them.  Please try to clean this up to be a [mre] where you have a single clearly defined issue and where all relevant errors are described explicitly in the question text.  Otherwise people have to hunt around figuring out the difference the problems you care about and the problems you don't care about.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @jcalz.  The static vs instance comment put me on the right lines, so I see that my 2 E's are not related.